# `join_table_conditions` for Sequel `one_through_one` association?

Tags: ruby, sequel

Sequel provides a `graph_join_table_conditions` option when defining a `many_to_many` or `one_through_one` association, which lets you set extra conditions on the join table when eager loading the association.

However, it doesn't appear that there is a corresponding method to use when **not** eager loading the association (e.g., `join_table_conditions`). There is a `join_table_block` option, but that doesn't seem to apply to querying.

Am I missing something? I know I could add:

```
conditions: { join_table__some_col: 'something' }
```

to the association settings, but that seems fragile when doing multiple joins or eager loading, etc....

Answer (score 1):

Passing a block to the associations method is probably the best way to accomplish that:

```
many_through_many :foos do |ds|
  ds.where(join_table__some_col: 'something')
end
```

The block is used when regular loading and eager loading using a query per association.  You'll still need to use `:graph_join_table_conditions` to handle eager loading via `eager_graph`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer (and thanks for the great library)!